# Excel UDF with two workbooks open

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I'm using a simple excel UDF to evaluate a string as a formula.

```
Function Eval(Ref As String)
           
    Application.Volatile
    Eval = Evaluate(Ref)
        
End Function
```

The strings are stored in a data table maintained by accounting, and I'm using power query to bring that into a margin sheet. My problem is there is the is a likelihood of a user having multiple workbooks open at the same time. Is there a way to keep it from trying to recalculate based on the other sheet?

The more I think about it the more I realize I should just have them store the formulas as formulas and use the 'show formulas' button.

But I'd still love to know if there's an answer to my question.

Comment: If you're calling this from a cell, try `Eval = Application.ThisCell.Parent.Evaluate(Ref)`.

Comment: @BigBen - This worked. Thank you.

Comment: @BigBen: Super interesting...  I did not know anything about `ThisCell`. I all the time used: `Eval = Application.Caller.Parent.Evaluate(Ref)`.

Comment: @FaneDuru - yes, `Application.Caller` is another approach

Comment: @BigBen: I just wanted to emphasize that I never heard about `ThisCell`, able to be used in such a circumstance... This does not mean that there are not a lot of other Excel issues I never heard about. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `Evaluate` to be performed in the context of the worksheet from which the function is called.

You can get a reference to that sheet with `Application.ThisCell.Parent`:

```
Eval = Application.ThisCell.Parent.Evaluate(Ref)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference a specific workbook, you can do so in the reference itself like this:

```
Ref = "[WorkbookFileName.xlsm]" & Ref
```

Or for the current workbook (this will resolve to the currently executing macro's workbook):

```
Ref = "[" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "]" & Ref
```

You could also refer to a specific sheet:

```
Ref = "SheetName!" & Ref
```

Or

```
Ref = "[WorkbookFileName.xlsm]SheetName!" & Ref
```

Then you can perform the Eval.